# How to add div with content instead of images in ngx-slick-carousel

Tags: angular, typescript, slick.js

I want to add multiple `<div>` with content in [ngx-slick-carousel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-slick-carousel) in my angular 12 app. Currently, it is sliding dummy images and I don't know how to add/replace images with divs.

Below is my current code.

**app.component.html**

```
<ngx-slick-carousel class="carousel" #slickModal="slick-carousel"
                    [config]="slideConfig" 
                    (init)="slickInit($event)"
                    (breakpoint)="breakpoint($event)"
                    (afterChange)="afterChange($event)"
                    (beforeChange)="beforeChange($event)">
     
     <div ngxSlickItem *ngFor="let slide of slides" class="slide"><img src="{{ slide.img }}" alt="" width="100%"></div>

</ngx-slick-carousel>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
  slides = [
    {img: "https://via.placeholder.com/600.png/021/fff"},
    {img: "https://via.placeholder.com/600.png/321/fff"},
    {img: "https://via.placeholder.com/600.png/422/fff"},
    {img: "https://via.placeholder.com/600.png/654/fff"}
  ];
  slideConfig = {"slidesToShow": 2, "slidesToScroll": 1};
```

Please help me to know how can I add divs instead of these image URLs.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to just replace the image with a div..?

Comment: @MikeOne Yes I did. This swipes a blank area there, but no div content visible.

Answer (score 1):

Easily you can add multiple `div` inside the carousel instead of images.

For example, add two individual `div` and shows only one at a time.

First, modify your slideConfig object in your ts file as follow.

```
  slideConfig = {
              "slidesToShow": 1, 
              "slidesToScroll": 1, 
              "arrows": false
            };
```

Second, under the tag `<ngx-slick-carousel>` in HTML file, you need to add two individual `ngxSlickItem` without mentioning `*ngFor`.

```
 <ngx-slick-carousel 
              class="carousel" 
              #slickModal="slick-carousel" 
              [config]="slideConfig">

      <div ngxSlickItem class="slide">
        <h1>First slide</h1>
      </div>

      <div ngxSlickItem class="slide">
        <h1>First slide 2</h1>
      </div>

 </ngx-slick-carousel>
```

Now, you can also control through the previous and the next button.

```
<button (click)="slickModal.slickPrev()">Previous</button>
<button (click)="slickModal.slickPause()">Pause</button>
```

For more than two content `div`, just need to add more `ngxSlickItem` with div and make sure the `slidesToShow` in `slideConfig` as your requirements.